# Nested drawer in stackNavigator closes modal on hide

Tags: react-navigation

I'm having a weird situation when navigating from a Drawer (with custom items) to a screen in a parent Stack will close that screen when the drawer is dismissed

(pseudocode)

```
StackNavigator({mode:modal})
--MainScreen (the drawer)
--ModalScreen


DrawerNavigator
  == CustomDrawer onPress={navigate('ModalScreen), closeDrawer()}
  -- Screen
```

So the app goes to the `ModalScreen` just fine, the problem is that if I close the drawer the `ModalScreen` closes as well

If I delete `closeDrawer()` the `ModalScreen` stays but when I close it the drawer is there behind still opened.

The only "workaround" I found was to ignore the warning saying I cannot render multiple navigators, pass the `StackNavigator.navigation` as `screenProps.rootNavigation` and do

`onPress={this.props.screenProps.rootNavigation.navigate('ModalScreen), closeDrawer()}`

which is not so good.

Example here https://snack.expo.io/rJ9jkvm5X

Is there any good solution for this? 
Thank you